# Pythonic way to compare sign of numpy array with Dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas data frame,df. The contents of the first row are as follows:

```
-1387.900
1    -1149.000
2     1526.300
3     1306.300
4     1134.300
5    -1077.200
6     -734.890
7     -340.870
8     -268.970
9     -176.070
10    -515.510
11     283.440
12     -55.148
13   -1701.800
14     -63.294
15    -270.720
16    2216.800
17    4251.200
18    1459.000
19    -613.680
```

Which is basically a series. I have a (1x20) numpy array, as follows:

```
array([[ 1308.22000654,  -920.02730748,  1285.54273707, -1119.67498439,
          789.50281435,  -331.14325768,   756.67399745,  -101.9251545 ,
          157.17779635,  -333.17043669,  -191.10517521,  -127.80219696,
          698.32168135,   154.30798847, -1055.54268665, -1795.96042107,
          202.53471769,    25.58830318,   793.63902134,   220.94259961]])
```

Now what I want is that for each cell value of this top row of df data frame, I need to check if the sign of that cell is same as that of the corresponding cell sign of the above numpy array. If the sign is different then for all the rows in df, for that corresponding co-ordinate, flip the signs of each corresponding co-ordinate value in df. For ex. if you see the first cell value. Df has -1387 while numpy array has 1380. So now the first column of df frame should have it's sign reversed. Same with other columns.

I am doing it using a for loop. 
 Like

```
for x in range(20):
   if(np.sign(Y1[0][x])!=np.sign(df.ix[0][x])):
       if(np.sign(Y1[0][x])==0 and np.sign(df.ix[0][x]>0)):
          df[x]=df[x]*1
       else: 
          df[x]=df[x]*(-1)
```

I also need to make sure that if np.sign(Y[x])=0 then the sign which it takes is not zero but +1. I can add that condition in the above code, but point is how to make it more pythonic?.

EDIT: I have added the code which I wrote which seems to work fine and flip the signs of df column based on the conditions mentioned above. ANy idea how to do this in pythonic way?

EDITII: I have one more doubt. My numpy array is supposed to be single dimensional. But as you see above it is coming as 2 dimensional and I have to unnecessarily access the cell by 2 indexes. Why is that?. This is how I created numpy array(Dot product of two 1x11025 row of a df with 11025x20 matrix giving 1x20 array. But it is coming as array of array as you see above. code to create numpy array:

```
Y1=np.dot(X_smilie_norm[0:1],W)
```

X_smilie_norm is a 28x11025 pandas dataframe. I am accessing just the first row of that and doing a dot product with W which is a 11025x20 matrix. It is giving a double dimensional array when all I want is a single dimensional so that I could access Y1 values just with single index.

Comment: IMO This would be much clearer with a 3x3 array (or something similarly small).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, but I don't know what the result you want when the first row of df contians zero.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 10, (10, 12)))
sign = np.random.randint(-10, 10, 12)
df.loc[:, (df.iloc[0] >= 0) ^ (sign >= 0)] *= -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mask and apply it to the dataframe

```
mask = (arr <= 0) != (df <= 0) # true if signs are different
df[mask] = -df[mask] # flip the signs on those members where mask is true
```